# titleBarOverlay option breaks draggable window in Electron.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron

I'm trying to use the `titleBarOverlay` option in electron.js but when I try to drag the window, it won't drag. When I remove the option, the dragging feature works like normal. Is there a workaround for this?

index.js:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
let mainWindow;

app.on('ready', () => {
     mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
          height: 600,
          width: 800,
          title: "Last Horizon",
          titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
          titleBarOverlay: {
              color: '#2e2e2e',
              symbolColor: '#ff6d4b'
          },
          webPreferences: {
             nodeIntegration: true
          }
     });
     mainWindow.removeMenu()
     mainWindow.loadFile('src/index.html');
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
     <head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
     </head>
     <body>
          <div class="titleBar"></div>
          <div class="main">
               <h1>Hello World!</h1>
          </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

styles.css

```
html, body {
     -webkit-app-region: drag;
     background-color: #2e2e2e;
     color: white;
}

.titleBar {
     /* -webkit-app-region: drag; */
     background-color: #ffffff;
     width: 100%;
     height: 32px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `BrowserWindow` needs to have it's `frame` option set to `false` else the native titleBar will display, which in turn is then used by the OS to drag the window around, not your designated html region.

`index.js`

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
let mainWindow;

app.on('ready', () => {
     mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
          height: 600,
          width: 800,
          title: "Last Horizon",
          titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
          titleBarOverlay: {
              color: '#2e2e2e',
              symbolColor: '#ff6d4b'
          },
          frame: false, // <-- Add this line
          webPreferences: {
             nodeIntegration: true
          }
     });
     mainWindow.removeMenu()
     mainWindow.loadFile('src/index.html');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
     <head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
     </head>
     <body>
          <div class="titleBar"></div>
          <div class="main">
               <h1>Hello World!</h1>
          </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

`styles.css`

```css
html, body {
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
    color: white;
}

.titleBar {
    -webkit-app-select: none; /* <-- Add this line */
    -webkit-app-region: drag; /* <-- Add this line */
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
}
```

See [Create frameless window](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/window-customization#create-frameless-windows) and [Set custom draggable region](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/window-customization#set-custom-draggable-region) for more information.

Additionally, see [BrowserWindow options](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) for more information on the interaction between `titleBarStyle` and `titleBarOverlay`.